# Java game decelaration

Tags: java, animation

I'm trying to make an animation at my game to decelerate some object, how can I calculate the distance that is going to do if I subtract 0.01?

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double des = 0.01;
    double speed = 4;
    double distance =0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 400 ; i++){
        distance+=speed;
        speed-=des;
    }
    System.out.println(distance);
    System.out.println(speed);
}
```

As you can see I made a for loop, but I would like to know if is there any existing formula?

Comment: Well first of all, if it's a game and not a simulation, then a formula will not help you since you most certainly want to, in each iteration of your game loop, draw the object you are animating to the screen.

Comment: This is not a complex calculation. Why did you thinking for a formula here?

Comment: This has very little to do with programming, but rather with an elementary school physics/maths course (I use the word elementary freely here, not sure if there are actual "elementary" schools anywhere). The position of the object after `i` iterations with initial speed of `speed` and initial position `pos` and acceleration `acc` will be `pos + i * speed + acc * (i^2) / 2`

Comment: check this post: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38453/how-do-i-implement-deceleration-for-the-player-character